# speech recognition times out too soon in android

Tags: java, android

This function starts speech recognition, but it times out too soon, where as if Speech recognition
is started from the IME keyboard (eg Google keyboard) it does not timeout so quickly. 
I need a way to start the same intent as is used by the google keyboard.

```
public void StartSpeechRecognitionActivity(){
    try{
        Intent intent = new   Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);
        main.startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECHRECOGNITION_RESULTCODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException error) {
        ShowAndSpeakMessage("Speech recognition is not supported by your device");
    } catch( RuntimeException error ) {
        Log.e( TAG, ERROR_PREFIX + Errors.toString(error) );
    } catch( Error error ) {
        Log.e( TAG, ERROR_PREFIX + Errors.toString(error) );
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                            "Voice recognition!");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This just works fine for me!

Comment: no its not actually i want, this intent time out after some seconds while i want intent will be open till user cancel

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. The listening times out in about half a second (immediately with offline enabled). Most of the time I can't start talking because it takes me more time to breath in.

Answer (score 0):

Then I think you need to make check in onError function .I am doing this in the following way . and It is working fine for me.

```
 public void onError(int error) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(error);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG+">"+ "FAILED " + errorMessage);
  if(errorMessage.contains("RecognitionService busy"))
  {  speech.stopListening();
    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);


  }else if(errorMessage.contains("No speech input")){
      speech.stopListening();
        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

    }else if(errorMessage.contains("No match")){
      speech.stopListening();

      speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

}
```

so you can make as much checks as much there are the types of error , or there could be the possibility of error in your case

I hope it would help you

Comment: This makes the phone beeping all the time. it's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find a combination to make it work with `startActivityForResult` wasn't possible so I created a demo project with `SpeechRecognizer`. It works ok and you can customise further to your liking. The beeping sound has been taken care of and you take pause while speaking without the speech recogniser stopping

[SpeechRecongitionDemo](https://github.com/Maliotis/SpeechRecognitionDemo/tree/master)

[image]

Comment: I run this. It keeps beeping. The muteAudio doesn't work for some reason. At least not always. I can hear the stop-start sound. The sound is not the biggest problem. The problem is between the beeps the recognition is not working and misses words (for example if it happens in the middle of a word).